# Build failing as plugin not defined google maps cordova

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Hello This is an ionic 2 porject in which I am using

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

After importing and solving issues related to, whenever I am trying to build it I get the error as shown in snapshot.[image]

I tried running it on actual ios simulator as well but to of no help.

Any idea how can we include plugins directly in typescript files and use same?

Comment: This is just Typescript complaining because it knows nothing about that *plugin* property, but as you can see, the gulp tasks ended successfully. *Most of the plugins won't work in the browser (or even in emulators)* so the best (and maybe the only) way to test the plugin, is on a real device.

Comment: I tried running the app on my actual iPhone but it still shows blank screen when we have console there..also is there any specific way to include this in typescript code?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-dont-work/55637/5?u=aaronksaunders see this thread in the forums, I have a working solution here